# Finding the directory entry for a given file on a damaged btrfs partition

Tags: data-recovery, btrfs

I have a damaged btrfs partition where a large part of the files could not be found using the documented commands (`btrfs rescue super-recover`, `btrfs restore` and `rescue chunk-recover`). However, I was able to find some of the files through scanning the whole partition by their content. The files were intact. In order to speed up finding more files, is there any way to find the corresponding directory entry now that I know the exact location where the file was stored on the partition? Of course assuming that the directory entry is still intact.